# How does the lock statement ensure intra processor synchronization?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, synchronization

I have a small test application that executes two threads simultaneously. One increments a `static long _value`, the other one decrements it. I've ensured with `ProcessThread.ProcessorAffinity` that the threads are associated with different physical (no HT) cores to force intra processor communication and I have ensured that they overlap in execution time for a significant amount of time.

Of course, the following does not lead to zero:

```
for (long i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
    _value += offset;
}
```

So, the logical conclusion would be to:

```
for (long i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
    Interlocked.Add(ref _value, offset);
}
```

Which of course leads to zero.

However, the following also leads to zero:

```
for (long i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
    lock (_syncRoot)
    {
        _value += offset;
    }
}
```

Of course, the `lock` statement ensures that the reads and writes are not reordered because it employs a full fence. However, I cannot find any information concerning synchronization of processor caches. If there wouldn't be any cache synchronization, I'd think I should be seeing deviation from 0 after both threads were finished?

**Can someone explain to me how `lock`/`Monitor.Enter/Exit` ensures that processor caches (L1/L2 caches) are synchronized?**

Comment: “I have ensured that they start at the same time”. Not exactly, you can't control how the OS schedules threads of your application with regards to other applications. But in most cases, this shouldn't matter.

Comment: Sorry, mis-formulation. I've ensured that they start at roughly the same time and I **have** ensured that they overlap in execution time. Updated the question. Thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cache coherence in this case does not depend on `lock`. If you use `lock` statement it ensures that your assembler commands are not mixed.
`a += b` is not an atomic to processor, it looks like:

- Load data into register from memory
- Increment data
- Store data back

And without lock it may be:

- Load data into register X from memory
- Load data into register Y from memory
- Increment data (in X)
- Decrement data (in Y)
- Store data back (from X)
- Store data back (from Y) // In this case increment is lost.

But it's not about cache coherence, it's a more high-level feature.

So, `lock` does not ensures that the caches are synchronized. Cache synchronization is a processor internal feature which does not depend on code. You can read about it [here](http://cid-6bb0096ed36cff3d.office.live.com/self.aspx/Public%20stuff/10.1.1.146.1821.pdf).

When one core writes a value to memory and then when the second core try to read that value it won't have the actual copy in its cache unless its cache entry is invalidated so a cache miss occurs. And this cache miss forces cache entry to be updated to actual value.

Comment: Note that not all processors (e.g. Blackfin) does cache coherency automatically in hardware. But probably all processors that have a .net implementation does..

Comment: Are you saying that cache coherency itself isn't something you are ever confronted with in software?

Comment: You can manipulate with cache from your code (prefetch or clear commands for example), but as far as I know you can not manipulate with cache coherence related things from your code.

Comment: To go along with this, Intel/AMD are toying with doing away with cache coherency because it is so chatty and become a huge issue with many core CPUs. Each time a CPU changes an address, it must broadcast to all other cores to flag any related cache-lines as dirty. Also, from what I've read, "atomic" changes are expensive on ARM multicore systems because there is no hardware cache-coherency. So lock/Interlocked are expensive calls for Win8 ARM multi-core systems. I can't remember where I read this, but I thought it interesting. This also makes ARM more transistor and power efficient, less work.

Answer (score 4):

The CLR memory model [guarantees (requires) that loads/stores can't cross a fence](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2007/11/10/CLR20MemoryModel.aspx). It's up to the CLR implementers to enforce this on real hardware, [which they do](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163715.aspx#S2). However, this is based on the advertised / understood behavior of the hardware, which [can](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2008/07/17/LoadsCannotPassOtherLoadsIsAMyth.aspx) be [wrong](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2009/05/17/LoadsCannotPassOtherLoadsRevisited.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The `lock` keyword is just syntactic sugar for a pair of `System.Threading.Monitor.Enter()` and `System.Threading.Monitor.Exit()` calls. The implementations of `Monitor.Enter()` and `Monitor.Exit()` put up a memory fence which entails performing architecture appropriate cache flushing. So your other thread won't proceed until it can see the stores that results from the execution of the locked section.

Comment: But what process makes the store visible to the other thread?