# Thread synchronization. Why exactly this lock isn't enough to synchronize threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Threads synchronization. How exactly lock makes access to memory 'correct'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131979/threads-synchronization-how-exactly-lock-makes-access-to-memory-correct)

This question is inspired by [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131979/threads-synchronization-how-exactly-lock-makes-access-to-memory-correct)

We got a following test class

```
class Test
{
    private static object ms_Lock=new object();
    private static int ms_Sum = 0;

    public static void Main ()
    {
        Parallel.Invoke(HalfJob, HalfJob);
        Console.WriteLine(ms_Sum);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void HalfJob()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50000000; i++) {
            lock(ms_Lock) { }// empty lock

            ms_Sum += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Actual result is very close to expected value 100 000 000 (50 000 000 x 2, since 2 loops are running at the same time), with around 600 - 200 difference (mistake is approx 0.0004% on my machine which is very low). No other way of synchronization can provide such way of approximation (its either a much bigger mistake % or its 100% correct)

We currently understand that such level of preciseness is because of program runs in the following way:

[image]

Time is running left to right, and 2 threads are represented by two rows.

where

- black box represents process of acquiring, holding and releasing the
- lock plus represents addition operation ( schema represents scale on 
  my PC, lock takes approximated 20 times longer than add)
- white box    represents period that consists of try to acquire lock,
  and further    awaiting for it to become available

Also lock provides full memory fence.

So the question now is: if above schema represents what is going on, what is the cause of such big error (now its big cause schema looks like very strong syncrhonization schema)? We could understand difference between 1-10 on boundaries, but its clearly no the only reason of error? We cannot see when writes to ms_Sum can happen at the same time, to cause the error.

**EDIT:** many people like to jump to quick conclusions. I know what synchronization is, and that above construct is not a real or close to good way to synchronize threads if we need correct result. Have some faith in poster or maybe read linked answer first. I don't need a way to synchronize 2 threads to perform additions in parallel, I am exploring this extravagant and yet efficient , compared to *any* possible and *approximate* alternative, synchronization construct (it does synchronize to some extent so its **not meaningless** like suggested)

Comment: its not a duplicate first of all, second that question doesn't have a definite answer yet, and has a marked answer that stops possible discussion to get the actual reason

Comment: IF you read the accepted answer it tells why this code has some chance to produce correct results but it can't guarantee correct result... also it tells you what the correct code needs to be and why it produces correct results...

Comment: Using `Interlocked.Increment(ref ms_Sum);` and ditching the lock all together will probably resolve your issue.

Comment: @vcsjones like I say, you suggest a 100% synchronization approach, I am asking what is the source of little error in this one.

Comment: No - Eric said it would be "An interesting experiment"... not that it would guarantee correct result !

Comment: `Nobody explained the residual error. It is caused by the Windows thread scheduler`

Comment: @Hans maybe... but the same code would behave differently on different platforms / CPUs / Windows versions etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very tight loop with not much going on inside it, so `ms_Sum += 1` has a reasonable chance of being executed in "just the wrong moment" by the parallel threads.

Why would you ever write a code like this in practice?

Why not:

```
lock(ms_Lock) { 
    ms_Sum += 1;
}
```

or just:

```
Interlocked.Increment(ms_Sum);
```

?

**-- EDIT ---**

Some comments on why would you see the error despite memory barrier aspect of the lock... Imagine the following scenario:

- Thread A enters the `lock`, leaves the `lock` and then is pre-empted by the OS scheduler.
- Thread B enters and leaves the `lock` (possibly once, possibly more than once, possibly millions of times).
- At that point the thread A is scheduled again.
- Both A and B hit the `ms_Sum += 1` at the same time, resulting in some increments being lost (because *increment = load + add + store*).

Comment: its a theoretical question obviously. in practice such code is a disaster.

Comment: yeah you a probably right and its exactly whats going on. No reason it cannot happen on the course of all those cycles. You provided the answer first in your edit.

Answer (score 7):

`lock(ms_Lock) { }` this is meaningless construct. `lock` gurantees exclusive execution of code inside it.

Let me explain why this empty `lock` decreases (but doesn't eliminate!) the chance of data corruption. Let's simplify threading model a bit:

1. Thread executes one line of code at time slice.
2. Thread scheduling is done in strict round robin manner (A-B-A-B).
3. Monitor.Enter/Exit takes significantly longer to execute than arithmetics. (Let's say 3 times longer. I stuffed code with `Nop`s that mean that previous line is still executing.)
4. Real `+=` takes 3 steps. I broke them down to atomic ones.

At left column shown which line is executed at the time slice of threads (A and B).
At right column - the program (according to my model).

```
A   B           
1           1   SomeOperation();
    1       2   SomeOperation();
2           3   Monitor.Enter(ms_Lock);
    2       4   Nop();
3           5   Nop();
4           6   Monitor.Exit(ms_Lock);
5           7   Nop();
7           8   Nop();
8           9   int temp = ms_Sum;
    3       10  temp++;
9           11  ms_Sum = temp;                          
    4           
10              
    5           
11              

A   B           
1           1   SomeOperation();
    1       2   SomeOperation();
2           3   int temp = ms_Sum;
    2       4   temp++;
3           5   ms_Sum = temp;                          
    3           
4               
    4           
5               
    5
```

As you see in first scenario thread B just can't catch thread A and A has enough time to finish execution of `ms_Sum += 1;`. In second scenario the `ms_Sum += 1;` is interleaved and causes constant data corruption. In reality thread scheduling is stochastic, but it means that thread A has more *change* to finish increment before another thread gets there.

Comment: this is not answer on the question, everyone understands that empty lock is a weird synchronization construct. Question is why it results in such a little error

Comment: It's not meaningless, although it is not used correctly here. It wiill still causes a full memory barrier -- even if the critical region is not used.

Comment: if it was meaningless results would be the same if whole string with lock was commented , but that lock provides 99.99% of synchronization that is required.

Comment: @Valentin Kuzub Going to bet the 0.01% won't happen on a shipped product? ;-)

Comment: @pst like I say, its clear that its a mistake and incorrect way to synchronize theads. Whos questioning that? Only question is, since it does APPEAR to be meaningless, it provides fantastic synchronization. Probably because writes never happen at the same time on different threads. So the question is, why they still do happen sometimes. As for production obviously putting += into lock is resolving all the problems.

Comment: @pst it is meaningless, because it doesn't provide any *consistent* effect. Just increases chances, when the real use for this construct to remove indeterminacy at all. See my upcoming edit with explanation of it's effect.

Comment: @Valentin Kuzub please see my previous comment and edit.

Comment: @Andrey I am not sure you read this question at all. First you say its meaningless construct, while its clearly not. Now this edit. I provided a schema with exact scale of addition and lock{} duration.( its not 3 times slower but much more) why do you replicate it? And while your answer now barely repeats my question you didn't even try to answer the original question, which was: WHY such beautiful synchronization schema still produces an error. Please take time to read answer marked as answer to see what this all was about.

Comment: @Valentin Kuzub I reread your question and to be honest I found out that I really didn't read it carefully first time. But this is mutual, you didn't read my answers/comments very carefully too, because I answered your *real* question. Let me state it again. 1) It is meaningless because it doesn't provide determinism, just play with chances. This can not be considered useful, because the only use of such constructs to turn indeterministic code to deterministic. It fails.

Comment: @Valentin Kuzub 2) "what is the cause of such big error"? In reality thread scheduling is stochastic, this means that you never know when thread really gets interrupted, so there is a chance for example that it happens right in the middle of increment.

Comment: well its clearly not mutual, your initial response looked more like a mock to me, than a real try to understand the issue I was describing, and the goal that I had with question (further understanding what is going on in this exact case). I am not some 1 point user who forgot to place m++ inside a lock and wonders what happened. anyway its a fairly meaningless discussion now indeed.

Answer (score 2):

As noted: `lock(ms_Lock) { }` locks an empty block and so does nothing. You still have a race condition with `ms_Sum += 1;`. You need:

```
lock( ms_Lock )
{
  ms_Sum += 1 ;
}
```

[Edited to note:]

Unless you properly serialize access to ms_Sum, you have a race condition. Your code, as written does the following (assuming the optimizer doesn't just throw away the useless lock statement:

- Acquire lock
- Release lock
- Get value of ms_Sum
- Increment value of ms_Sum
- Store value of ms_Sum

Each thread may be suspended at any point, even in mid-instruction. Unless it is specifically documented as being atomic, it's a fair bet that any machine instruction that takes more than 1 clock cycle to execute may be interrupted mid-execution.

So let's assume that your lock is actually serializing the two threads. There is still nothing in place to prevent one thread from getting suspended (and thus giving priority to the other) whilst it is somewhere in the middle of executing the last three steps.

So the first thread in, locks, release, gets the value of ms_Sum and is then suspended. The second thread comes in, locks, releases, gets the [same] value of ms_Sum, increments it and stores the new value back in ms_Sum, then gets suspended. The 1st thread increments its now-outdates value and stores it.

There's your race condition.

Comment: try to run code with empty lock and without it to see that it does 99.99% of synchronization job needed here

Comment: this is probably correct, but Branko was first

Answer (score 2):

As noted the statement

`lock(ms_Lock) {}`

will cause a *full memory barrier*. In short this means the value of `ms_Sum` will be flushed between all caches and updated ("visible") among all threads.

However, `ms_Sum += 1` is *still not atomic* as it is just short-hand for `ms_Sum = ms_Sum + 1`: a read, an operation, and an assignment. It is in this construct that there is still a race condition -- the count of `ms_Sum` could be *slightly lower* than expected. I would also expect that the difference to be *more* without the memory barrier.

Here is a hypothetical situation of why it might be lower (A and B represent threads and a and b represent thread-local registers):

```
A: read ms_Sum -> a
B: read ms_Sum -> b
A: write a + 1 -> ms_Sum
B: write b + 1 -> ms_Sum // change from A "discarded"
```

This depends on a very particular order of interleaving and is dependent upon factors such as thread execution granularity and relative time spent in said non-atomic region. I suspect the `lock` itself will reduce (but not eliminate) the chance of the interleave above because each thread must wait-in-turn to get through it. The relative time spent in the lock itself to the increment may also play a factor.

Happy coding.

---

As others have noted, use the critical region established by the lock or one of the atomic increments provided to make it truly thread-safe.

Comment: yeah on the schema whole [+] block represents read  , and write. It takes 20 times less than acquire-hold-release lock. If they could be happening at the same time on different threads it would be a reason for missing values. If we run this without lock we only will see around 75% out of 100% expected. However in reality there is a very little loss%. It means [+] actually happen on different threads at the same time VERY RARELY. I am asking when is that, in which case, for which reason?

Comment: @Valentin Kuzub What if there are *many* `ms_Sum += 1` per loop? I would expect the drift to increase -- I suspect the `lock` may play a factor in getting the threads to "line up" in order which may minimize the interleaving. If this is the case it would make sense that doing more operations between each `lock` would increase the error observed.

Comment: well its logical that the longer time instructions between lock take compared to acquire-hold-release lock duration the more collisions will occur, question is about when can collisions happen currently.

Comment: This is it. The memory barrier is greatly reducing the "error" because it's keeping the CPU caches more synchronized, essentially by polling. Without the barrier, the caches are allowed to go way out of sync. This could be tested by using an explicit barrier instead of the lock() {}. Also for increment, you could always just use InterlockedIncrement, which makes the +=1 atomic.

Comment: @Chris Smith its not because of memorybarrier. Its because of situation that is happening like I describe on graph in question. If you take time and actually surround ms_Sum++ with Thread.MemoryBarrier() calls you will be surprised with actual mistake size that will be produced. (its huge)

Answer (score 0):

The += operator is not atomic, that is, first it reads then it writes the new value. In the mean time, between reading and writing, the thread A could switch to the other B, in fact without writing the value... then the other thread B don't see the new value because it was not assigned by the other thread A... and when returning to the thread A it will discard all the work of the thread B.